# Level sets and integral of functions of two variables

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, inequalities, isoperimetric-problems

Let $f_1,f_2$ be two positive functions on $\Omega_1, \Omega_2 \subset R^2$ with $f_1|_{\partial \Omega_1}=f_2|_{\partial \Omega_2}=0$. For every $\lambda>0$,  denote the the area of the domain enclosed by $f_{i}=\lambda$ by $A_i(\lambda)$, $i=1,2$. Assume

$A_1(\lambda) \leq A_2(\lambda)$ for all $\lambda >0$.

Is

$\int_{\Omega_1}f_1 dx \leq \int_{\Omega_2}f_2 dx?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what you mean by "enclosed by". If this is just the set of points where $f_i(x)>\lambda$, then the answer is "yes", since $$\int_\Omega fdx=\int_0^\infty A(\lambda)d\lambda.$$ This is just Fubuni's theorem applied to the subgraph of $f$.

Comment: No, $A(\lambda)=Area({x:f(x)>\lambda})$.

Comment: According  to your question $A(\lambda)$  is an *area*.  Kostya's formula is correct and it is a trick frequently used in probability theory when computing the expectation of  a nonnegative random variable $X$,  $$E[X]=\int_0^\infty P(X>\lambda)d\lambda.$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course, if the word "enclosed" is understood properly. This follows from the definition of Lebesgue's integral. Lebesgue's original definition was the following: this is the limit of sums
$$\sum\lambda_j\mathrm{area}\{ x:\lambda_j<f\leq \lambda_{j+1}\}.$$

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I don't see how $area\{ x: \lambda_j< f_1\leq \lambda_{j+1}\} \leq area\{ x: \lambda_j< f_2\leq \lambda_{j+1}\}$ follows from the assumptions.

Comment: Integrate by parts and you obtain the formula in Kostia_I answer.